# ¿Como puedo ordenar una lista alfabeticamente en C++?

Tags: c++, array, lista, ordenamiento

Quisiera saber como puedo ordenar una lista alfabeticamente en C++, siendo todas las palabras de tres letras.

Logro ordenarlo por la primera letra, pero no por las segunda y tercer letra.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < string.size() - 1; j++){
        // Compara la primera letra de cada palabra.
        if (string[j][0] > string[j+1][0]){
            // Swap
            t = string[j];
            string[j] = string[j+1];
            string[j+1] = t;
        } 
    }
}
```

Ese ordenamiento tiene cierto estilo de Bubble Sort pero no logro aplicarlo a las otras letras.

Gracias.

Comment: Que has intentado amigo? muestra tu esfuerzo para poder colaborarte.

Comment: Te aconsejo colocarlo en tu pregunta de tu publicación lo que intentaste sino te eliminaran la publicación. Así sera mas fácil poder ver tu código y utilizarlo para ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que necesitas iterar por tres letras necesitas un bucle... lo único que hace el bucle es reemplazar `[0]` por `[i]`:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++ )
{
  char a = string[j][i];
  char b = string[j+1][i];

  if( a > b] )
  {
    // Swap
    string[j] = b
    string[j+1] = a;
  }
  else if( a < b )
  {
    break; // La secuencia está ordenada
  }
}
```

Bueno, adicionalmente hay que verificar un caso que no has contemplado, y que sabemos que las dos palabras están ordenadas cuando la letra actual de la primera palabra es *menor*  que la correspondiente a la segunda palabra... asumiendo que las anteriores (si las hubiese) son iguales:

```
abc acc -> a=a, b<c -> no hay que seguir, están ordenadas
azz baa -> a<b      -> no hay que seguir, están ordenadas
```

Answer (score 1):

En la libreria cstring existe la función

```
strcmp(A,B);
```

que compara dos cadenas A y B y devuelve:

- -1: Si alfabéticamente A es menor que B
- 0 : Si son iguales
- 1 : Si alfabéticamente B es menos que A

Usando esta función, tu algoritmo quedaría más o menos así:

```
   for (i=1; i<string.size(); i++){
         for j=0 ; j<string.size() - 1; j++){
              if (strcmp(string[j],string[j+1])>0){
                  temp = string[j];
                  string[j] = string[j+1];
                  string[j+1] = temp;
              }
         }
    }
```